# Zenmap installation problem and erro of no location of packages

Tags: parrot-os

I can not install zenmap on my parrot os version 6.0. Any solution fo this problem

I try to add respositories but it failed to save it.

I have tried different ways to solve it but it still fails. Please help me.

Let me know if any one can solve it and how can it be solved